# Interval triggering for large windows in beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, triggers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stream-processing

My Beam pipeline uses large event time windows to calculate averages and further stats over data where every second i get a new event. I use Kafka as my streaming source.
I do however want to emit early results in a given interval.
I am using the following window and trigger.

```
.apply(Window
            .into(SlidingWindows.of(duration).every(advance))
            .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                .withEarlyFirings(
                    AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(triggerDelay)))
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
            .accumulatingFiredPanes())
```

This is working as far as i get early results. I do however get multiple outputs per triggerDelay with the same calculations instead of the single result of the window up until this point in time.
It looks like the following:

```
Stats{count=209, mean=10.0, populationStandardDeviation=0.0, min=10.0, max=10.0}
Stats{count=209, mean=10.0, populationStandardDeviation=0.0, min=10.0, max=10.0}
Stats{count=209, mean=10.0, populationStandardDeviation=0.0, min=10.0, max=10.0}
...
...
Stats{count=209, mean=10.0, populationStandardDeviation=0.0, min=10.0, max=10.0}
Stats{count=209, mean=10.0, populationStandardDeviation=0.0, min=10.0, max=10.0}
Stats{count=209, mean=10.0, populationStandardDeviation=0.0, min=10.0, max=10.0}
```

Is it possible that the early firing trigger fires for every event that arrives instead of once after the triggerDelay? Is there a way to define a trigger that only fires once every x seconds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the duration, advance and triggerDelay typical values?

Comment: Duration would be 30 days, advance 1day and triggerDelay from 1 Seconds up to a minute depending on the performance

Comment: Is it your test configuration? Because you could have multiple processing of the same message, in multiple windows. In production, after 30 days, 30 windows will be open, and a message will trigger 1 event in 30 windows, and so, you will see it 30 times!

Comment: Oh thank you ver much. That was my mistake. I didnt expect that already 30 windows would be opened. So the trigger always produced the right results, just not what i expected.

Comment: Could you promote your comment to an answer?